# Trying to prevent an implicit conversion using arithmetic operators

Tags: c++, visual-studio, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

Is there a way to force a compile time error when there is a implicit conversion using the arithmetic operators. For example:

```
class A:
public:
A operator + (const A tmp) const;
void setX(const int X)
void setY(const int Y)
void setZ(const int Z)
private: 
template <typename Y> 
Y operator +(const Y tmp);

main: 
int a1 {2};
int a2 {3};
int a3 {4}'

char b1 {2};
char v2 {3};
char b3 {4};

A a;
a.setX(a1);
a.sety(a2);
a.setz(a3);

A b;
b.setx(b1);
b.sety(b2);
b.setz(b3);
A d= a+b; //more or so of what i mean. This should be an error
A e= a+a;  // this should not be because its the same type
```

the problem is that when i create a template for the operator both a+b and a+c generate an error. Which is confusing to me because a+c is the only one that should generate an error.

Comment: You need to provide a piece of code that can actually be used to reproduce the error. `a + b` (where `a`, `b` have type `int`) should never cause a compile-time error.

Comment: You cannot change operators for C++ types like `int` `char` `double` etc. You can only do that for user defined types.

Comment: Added some code to give you an idea of what im talking about

Comment: @Slava you can prevent implicits conversions for methods like setX but you cant do that for an operator + ?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. both `a` and `b` have the same type, there is no way to differentiate `a+b` from `a+a` in the type system. You can force the template to not be used for the same type by doing the following: `template <typename Y, class = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::decay<Y>::type, A>::value>::type> 
Y operator +(const Y &tmp);`

Comment: @n314159 so by doing a template on that operator it would generate an error no matter what because a and b are both the objects of A?

Comment: Yes, either both `a+b` and `a+a` generate an error or neither.

Comment: @n314159  Ok that makes a lot of sense thanks!

Comment: @Jay you changed your question since I commented. Point is you cannot create your own operators for standard types. So you cannot create your own `operator+(int,int)` and as such you cannot create any additional restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

An implicit conversion will take place whenever the types of both parameters does not match. Yo can check this when compiling with something like

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), decltype(c)>::value);
```